# 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, attributes

Running Python on a Windows system I encountered issues with loading a JSON file into memory. What is wrong with my code?

```
>>> import json
>>> array = json.load({"name":"Name","learning objective":"load json files for data analysis"})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    array = json.load({"name":"Name","learning objective":"load json files for data analysis"})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\json\__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Answer (score 30):

Since you want to convert it into `json` format, you should use `json.dumps()` instead of `json.load()`. This would work:

```
>>> import json
>>> array = json.dumps({"name":"Galen","learning objective":"load json files for data analysis"})
>>> array
'{"learning objective": "load json files for data analysis", "name": "Galen"}'
```

**Output:**

```
>>> a = json.loads(array)
>>> a["name"]
u'Galen'
```

Comment: `json.dumps()` returns a string and not a json object.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to load json from a string you need to add quotes around your string and there is a different method to read from file or variable. For variable it ends with "s" other doesn't

```
import json

my_json = '{"my_json" : "value"}'

res = json.loads(my_json)
print res
```

Answer (score -2):

As you said, it is wrong, you forgot the ' before and after the json text.

```
import json
array = json.load('{"name":"Galen","learning objective":"load json files for data analysis"}')
```

I had the same mistake :)

dumps works but it is not the same. Load is better for parsing json. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: `json.load()` doesn't work on strings. It needs a file object.

Comment: @asmaier try it in python 2 (see the doc i attach) and tell me it doesn't work

Comment: You probably mean `json.loads()`, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43828487/179014.