# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read' while using Tweepy

Tags: python

I am completely new to python. I am not able to run the following code as it throws an attribute error. Could someone please help?

```
import tweepy
import urllib

import json


api_key = "VdG3NjsNKg49NbNb7GMHiX"
api_secret = "yBGKwe2K3QYk5lDny1eIKiyEQawVLQKX1HbRCTRfA9hK9"
access_token_key = "110456973-H8CAAET5CBoEa6FS4CKmk98XOADnJOsxK45"
access_token_secret = "wPUlfaxs1TFrTlXs2VqJIE5ffAfclhJCWmMlLPncb"


auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(api_key,api_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key,access_token_secret)
api=tweepy.API(auth,parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())

results=api.search(q="microsoft",count=100)

print type(results)
print json.load(results)
```

Comment: Are those your **real** Twitter Access Tokens?

Comment: the type of results is `dict`. what are you trying to do with the last line?

Comment: If these are your actual tokens, you should change them right now. Remember the edit history is visible too, so it's not enough to delete them from the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['dict' object has no attribute 'read'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415193/dict-object-has-no-attribute-read)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
results=api.search(q="microsoft",count=100)

print type(results)
print json.load(results)
```

`results` here is already a `dict`.

There is no need to deserialize it as JSON.

See: [`tweepy.api.API.search()`](http://pythonhosted.org//tweepy/api.html#API.search) which reads:

> `API.search(q[, lang][, locale][, rpp][, page][, since_id][,
>   geocode][, show_user])`

```
Returns tweets that match a specified query.

Parameters: 
    q – the search query string
    lang – Restricts tweets to the given language, given by an ISO 639-1 code.
    locale – Specify the language of the query you are sending. This is intended for language-specific clients and the default should work in the majority of cases.
    rpp – The number of tweets to return per page, up to a max of 100.
    page – The page number (starting at 1) to return, up to a max of roughly 1500 results (based on rpp * page.
    geocode – Returns tweets by users located within a given radius of the given latitude/longitude. The location is preferentially taking from the Geotagging API, but will fall back to their Twitter profile. The parameter value is specified by “latitide,longitude,radius”, where radius units must be specified as either “mi” (miles) or “km” (kilometers). Note that you cannot use the near operator via the API to geocode arbitrary locations; however you can use this geocode parameter to search near geocodes directly.
    show_user – When true, prepends “<user>:” to the beginning of the tweet. This is useful for readers that do not display Atom’s author field. The     default is false.

Return type:    
    list of SearchResult objects
```

**NB:** The "Return type:"

Comment: Yes it most certainly would!